# Can I hide controls on ChewieController at some point in flutter?

Tags: flutter, controller, controls

I have created a ChewieContoller which looks like this:

```
_chewieController = ChewieController(
  videoPlayerController: widget.videoPlayerController,
  aspectRatio: 16/9,
  autoInitialize: true,
  autoPlay: true,
  showOptions: false,
  showControls: true,
  errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
    return Center(
      child: Text(
        errorMessage,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Now `showControls` is set to `true`, but at some point I want to change it to false (I want to hide controls). But when I try to do something like this:

```
_chewieController.showControls = false;
```

Flutter gives an error saying **'showControls' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
Try finding a different setter, or making 'showControls' non-final.**

Is there a way to change showControls propety?

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a new instance with the same videoPlayerController.

```
_chewieController = ChewieController(
  videoPlayerController: _chewieController.videoPlayerController,
  aspectRatio: 16/9,
  autoInitialize: true,
  autoPlay: true,
  showOptions: false,
  showControls: true,
);
```